# How make an array with a defined number of elements in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to make an array with only 3 elements. How I do this while defining an empty array? I've seen similar posts, but I'm not sure if I can do this in Swift

```
//I want to make it like this:
var numberOfElementsInArray = 3
var array = [0, 0, 0]//there are 3 zeros because the first var is 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var array = Array(repeating: 0, count:numberOfElementsInArray) // = [0,0,0]
```